# Django Blog App urls functionality

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to integrate the following blog APP https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps ,so in my main urls.py i have included the blog urls as `(r'^blog/',include('basic.blog.urls')),`  Now my question is that now when i point my browser to the blog APP http://127.0.0.1/blog/ i get a message as "Post archive",How to proceed from here i.e, how to post blog and retrieve the same.What is the url to be used..The following is the blog urls

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *


urlpatterns = patterns('basic.blog.views',
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    view='post_detail',
    name='blog_detail'
),
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$',
    view='post_archive_day',
    name='blog_archive_day'
),
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$',
    view='post_archive_month',
    name='blog_archive_month'
),
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$',
    view='post_archive_year',
    name='blog_archive_year'
),
url(r'^categories/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    view='category_detail',
    name='blog_category_detail'
),
url (r'^categories/$',
    view='category_list',
    name='blog_category_list'
),
url(r'^tags/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    view='tag_detail',
    name='blog_tag_detail'
),
url (r'^search/$',
    view='search',
    name='blog_search'
),
url(r'^page/(?P<page>\d+)/$',
    view='post_list',
    name='blog_index_paginated'
),
url(r'^$',
    view='post_list',
   name='blog_index'
),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no URLs specific to post creation, so you need to do it via the Admin interface. I looked at the code and there is a specific template for creating/modifying `post` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used this blogging app, but im guessing because it suggests its "basic" it will just provide the bare bones. So my starting point would be to add a post and see what happens.

If going to /blog/ doesnt provide a way to add a post, then register the models with your admin site and add through that way. Im guessing that you may have to build your own adding sections...

If you dont want to do this, [djang-blog-zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia) is a blogging app i have used, and really like it

Comment: I am using python 2.4 and cant install setuptools http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027484/setuptools-for-python2-4

Comment: setup tools? what do you need them for? what blog was this to do with?

Answer (score 0):

I've used and customized the basic blog application

The creation can be done through the Admin interface, the models are already registered with the admin interface

You just need to provide a good layout and some cool stylesheets for your front end to get started